# Laravel Custom Presenter / Pagination Class 'Illuminate\Pagination\Presenter' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination

Hey guys I am creating a custom Laravel 5 pagination presenter using https://laravelista.com/laravel-custom-pagination-presenter as a guide, I have followed the instruction but my App is having problem finding the Illuminate\Pagination\Presenter class ( which i am extending from ).

I am calling the presenter in my view

view

```
 <div class="cf">
    <div class="columns large-6 text-left paginate">

    <?php 
        $presenter = new App\Pagination\Presenters\customPresenter($paginator);

....
```

There error that i am receiving is

```
FatalErrorException in customPresenter.php line 7:
Class 'Illuminate\Pagination\Presenter' not found
```

My CustomPresenter class looks like;

```
<?php 

namespace App\Pagination\Presenters;

use Illuminate\Pagination\Presenter;

class customPresenter extends Presenter { << error occurs here

/**
 * Get the previous page pagination element.
 *
 * @param  string  $text
 * @return string
 */
public function getPrevious($text = '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>')
{
    // If the current page is less than or equal to one, it means we can't go any
    // further back in the pages, so we will render a disabled previous button
    // when that is the case. Otherwise, we will give it an active "status".
    if ($this->currentPage <= 1)
    {
        return $this->getDisabledTextWrapper($text);
    }
```

....

Am I missing a package? I have done a composer update and added my customPresenter class to the autoload.

Any help greatly appreciated

cheers

Comment: Looks like that's a Laravel 4 tutorial. Laravel 5 doesn't have a `Illuminate\Pagination\Presenter`. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator

Comment: Good find, add it as an answer and I will accept, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `use` statement to:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\Presenter
```

You can also extend one of the existing presenters, e.g (file is located in `App\Extensions` folder).

```
<?php namespace App\Extensions;

use Illuminate\Pagination\BootstrapThreePresenter;
use Illuminate\Support\HtmlString;

class CustomPagination extends BootstrapThreePresenter {

    public function render()
    {
        if ($this->hasPages()) {
            return new HtmlString(sprintf(
                '<ul class="pagination pagination-sm no-margin pull-right">%s %s %s</ul>',
                $this->getPreviousButton(),
                $this->getLinks(),
                $this->getNextButton()
            ));
        }

        return '';
    }

}
```

And you can then use this in your blade using:

```
{{ with(new App\Extensions\CustomPagination($data))->render() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the Niraj Shah answer, a good tip that I found is call the presenter method in the controller:

```
$data->presenter(function($paginator) {
    return new App\Extensions\CustomPagination($paginator)
});
```

Now the result with links() or render() is the CustomPagination.

Note: $data is a Paginator instance.